How to create extension on postgresql?
I build postgresql by docker compose and I can not create extension vector.
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
      container_name: postgres_container
      image: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-changeme}
        PGDATA: /data/postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres:/data/postgres
        - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      networks:
        - postgres
      restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    postgres:       

I access to postgresql container:
docker exec -it <postgresql-container-name> bash

I create a extension:
CREATE EXTENSION vector;

Here's error:
ERROR:  extension "vector" is not available
DETAIL:  Could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/16/extension/vector.control": No such file or directory.
HINT:  The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.


I can not understand what it means. How can I fix this

First you have to install the extension before using it.Check whether you have the shared library(extensionName.so) file generated or not in the  /postgres/lib directory after make install.
Below is the basic make file to create the shared library for your extension.This make file will combine all the objects files generated during the building phase of your extension.
MODULE_big =<extensionName>
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c)) 
$(info objectsssss ${OBJS}) 
PG_CONFIG = /path/to/pg_config 
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs) 
include $(PGXS)

Follow below any of the links for your reference.

https://www.percona.com/blog/writing-postgresql-extensions-is-fun-c-language/

https://www.highgo.ca/2019/10/01/a-guide-to-create-user-defined-extension-modules-to-postgres/

https://big-elephants.com/2015-10/writing-postgres-extensions-part-i/



Do you have any tutorial or guideline? I read your answer that I really don't know what to do next? :(

Is vector extension is created by you?

I have added few links go through it once.

Hi, I got it. But I run postgres from docker. Can you provide docker compose file for this case?
